How to know which completion function is being called?
I want to type somethingTabTab and know exactly which completion function gets called, so that I can use that function for completion of aliases.
This is to solve the following problem:
git push -d originTabTab works properly. Some completion function exists there and is being called. I just don't which one. Because of that...
# ...I can't do:
alias del='git push -d origin'
_git_complete del _git_push_dash_d_origin # no such function!

#...like I would for:
alias cm='git commit'
_git_complete cm _git_commit # works fine!

Bash completion is a very complex subject, which I don't get well and don't really care. Just want a way to print the name of the completion function being used, if that's possible.

There's probably some completion related builtin that will give you the answer quickly, but while waiting for someone to tells us which one, you can tryPS4=' $BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO:$FUNCNAME > '; set -x then git push -d origin <Tab>. There will be a lot of debug output, but you can probably look at the first few lines to figure out which is the main function being called.
